# How to convert X Y coordinates to latitude and longitude using a MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I insert map coordinates from a txt file into my database. My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `zone` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `X` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Y` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `depth` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `latitude` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `longitude` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));
```

The points I insert in my table contain and ID, an X and Y coordinate,and empty latitude and longitude columns. I want to make a trigger so when I insert a point in the table(for example:(X)240005.400 (Y)5176335.820 (depth)15.954),before the line gets inserted, the  X and Y coordinates are converted to latitude and longitude(in order to make them appear on Google Maps).

If it helps:

ABSCISS OF CENTRAL MERIDIAN: 304800

FACTOR-SCALE AT THE CENTRAL MERIDIAN: 0.9999

ELLIPSOID:
    a : 6378137
    b : 6356752.314
    m : 111132.08937

I have very limited experience with triggers, and so I'm asking if there is a quick way to convert X and Y  TO LAT/LON using a trigger.Thanks.

Comment: You're not making a whole lot of sense

Comment: You don't seem to understand what you are trying to do... Can you explain the context ?

Comment: sorry if I was unclear. the points I enter in my DB table each have an ID, an X coordinate, and an Y coordinate, as well as a latitude and longitude coordinates, which are empty at the moment I insert the points. What I want to do is make a trigger that converts the aforementioned XY coordinates to the LAT/LONG and insert them in their respective columns. Please tell me if I am still unclear.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but X and Y can't just be "converted" to any latitude and longitude just like that. X and Y from what ? You should edit your question

Comment: they are points on a map. I need to show theses points on Google Maps. However the  X and Y coordinates are not compatible in the Google maps API. I need to convert them to latitude and longitude in order to make them appear on a google map.

Comment: I understand that, but what is X and Y ? Maybe you can edit your question giving an examples of your "points" ?

Comment: Where are 0,0 in the X and Y plane? Do we need to take into account that the Earth is a oblate spheroid and hence some distortion is required when mapping to a plan surface

Comment: BTW, is the question about some kind of maths or using trigger ? Because if you don't know how to use triggers, you can [check the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html). But if the problem is about "converting" your data to lat / lon, it is out of topic on StackOverflow... More likely suited for [this website](https://math.stackexchange.com/), I guess !